# How to study and follow a lecture if it feels like the professor is info dumping and cramming too much information in 1 class period?

Tags: undergraduate, university, lecture-teaching-method

I am taking 8 classes my spring sophomore semester as a finance major and 3 of which feel like the professors are info dumping without following the textbook, lecture slides, and scheduled chapters. One of the teachers side tracks all the time talking about his glory days in consulting while, name dropping random companies that were founded by former students, and giving his own version of the topic because "The textbook is too fluffy". The other one covers 60+ lecture slides per class period "2 hours" and the last one overcomplicates the concepts and relies on the TA for any questions... How should I go about handling this because I feel like I would have a better time studying on my own and going over the textbook and slides by myself than go to those classes and trip over my feet. This is mainly to do with I don't know what to actually go over because it feels like an info dumping session with literally no topic connections.

Comment: Where is it even possible to take eight classes?

Comment: Do these instructors make their slides available?

Comment: Having a professor not "follow the textbook" is a distinct advantage because you get two views of the subject matter.

Answer (score 7):

Your question seems to voice essentially four concerns:

1. The teacher(s) don't follow the textbook
2. You find the presentation complicated
3. You are unsure what to read in the textbook
4. The teachers either cover too much material or use too many slides for you to keep up.

Some academics would suggest that the whole point of having a lecture is to do something different from the textbook --- i.e., to put a different slant on things, to try and engage you in the topic in a way that is different from the textbook in case you don't find the textbook engaging, and so forth.

Nonetheless, it seems as though your main concern is related to the fact that you are unsure what you ought to be reading in the textbook. The obvious solution is to *ask*. Unless you particularly wish to, there is no need to remark on how you are finding the lectures; you need only say, at the end of each class, that you are unsure what parts of the textbook would be most appropriate for self-study of the relevant material.

On a slightly different note, you might also consider reading the syllabus and/or stated learning-outcomes for the course. Those two things should give you additional guidance about what material is essential, and what is not.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would have the following components.

Attend lectures and take notes on things that are relevant to the topic and likely to be tested. Ignore the cruft. You aren't likely to be asked about the instructor's past successes.

If the textbook is, indeed, inadequate, see if you can find a better one. Unfortunately this can be costly, though for many subjects used older editions are adequate.

Use whatever printed or online sources are available to learn the relevant material. Do whatever exercises you have been given and additional ones if possible to solidify your knowledge. Reading isn't enough. Watching isn't enough.

Ask a lot of questions about the material in class to try to bring the topic back into the proper lane.

Form a study group of other students to discuss course material. Such a group might discuss ideas from more than one course.

Get a bunch of students to collectively complain to authorities.

If some of these courses aren't needed, drop them to focus on more productive things.

---

In secondary school I once had a course in which the instructor was probably incapable of teaching the subject and nothing was learned nor expected to be learned. He was never on topic. Passing was easy as there were no challenges. Just a few wasted hours per week. I was assigned to the course, though I favored a different one, because the advisor suggested it would "look good" on my transcript. I had to learn the material of that other course on my own because it was more relevant to my goals. I was too introverted and shy to think about complaining, however. All the other students recognized the issue and we had a few (sad) laughs about it. Most of us were college-bound and it *did* look fine on the transcript. Sad, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to say these approaches are common, but I have also encountered them. From my point of view, it would be best to find out from older students how the exams were conducted and what is required. In school, it is not always about being able to do something but navigating its environment, hidden power games, etc.

Older students who have completed such subjects are a valuable source of information. Of course, everyone has a different opinion on this, so it is better to consult with a more significant number of graduates.

If you cannot contact older students, I recommend using frequent consultations, where, on the one hand, the teacher will remember you and be more lenient during the assessment. At the same time, you can get to know them better.

It may sound like a waste of time, but if you are a student at a formal school, your goal is not to learn something but to pass the exams and graduate from that school with success. The university is already a school of life because the approach of some professors reflects the approach of some of your future colleagues.

Finally, if you cannot learn it their way and are still interested in learning it, finding another way is standard practice - friends, online courses, other courses, etc.